# read password protected excel file with node

Tags: node.js, excel, xlsx

I want to read a password protected `.xlxs` file , i have looked at a package that helps me read password protected `.xlxs` files, but reading seems a little hard with that package as my excel sheets can be of different columns. Any help would be appreciated

Packages i have looked at:

[xlsx populate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx-populate) Here reading is quite hard

[xlxs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) Here in documentation the config for passing password to read file is given but throws 500 error as is it not implemented

XLSX package that gives error

`var workbook = XLSX.readFile('./Match57.xlsx',{password  : '1234'});`

Error :

`throw new Error("File is password-protected");
    ^
    Error: File is password-protected`

Comment: For downvote , please comment why so i can improve

Comment: you should include the code that gives you error 500

Comment: I am currently hitting the same problem. With the xlsx package password protection is pro feature.
Will update once I find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just a hint for future fellow Googlers. The option 'password' of the XLSX.read method is meant for the weak protection mechanism in older Excel formats. Unencrypting excelsheets is not available in the open source version of SheetJS.  Source: https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs/issues/774